# Moving div horizontally while it's moving vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, keyevent

I am currently creating a game, a platformer. I already have the character moving around horizontally, however, I do not really know how I will make him jump... and move at the same time.

I decided not to use jQuery `animate` to move the character around, therefore I have no idea how to enable the character to move at the same time as a jump. I have seen an example of perfect jumping and moving with jQuery on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L86bdw0/1/), however it uses `animate`.

How can I make the character jump (smoothly), **and**
be able to move while jump at the same time (without using animate)?

I have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/FlipFloop/pen/aBBYPz) (the CSS in the Pen is SCSS, but it's CSS here), but here is the code anyways:

```js
var game_anim = function() {

 var level = [
  [0, 1, "l", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, "l", "l", 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3],
 ];

 var $player = $(".player");
 var $game = $(".game");

 $(document).keydown(function(event) { // keycodes: left = 37, right = 39
  if (event.which == 39 || event.which == 68) { // right arrow or D
   if ($player.position().left < $game.width() - $player.width()) {
    $player.css("left", "+=10");
   }
  }
  if (event.which == 37 || event.which == 81 || event.which == 65) { // left arrow or Q on AZERTY or A on QWERTY
   if ($player.position().left > 0) {
    $player.css("left", "-=10");
   }
  }

  if (event.which == 38) {
   if ($player.position().top > 0) {
    $player.css("top", "-=10");
   }
  }

 });

 

}

$(document).ready(function() {

 game_anim();

});
```

```css
.game {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 800px)/2);
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.stone {
  background-color: black;
}

.lava {
  background-color: red;
}

.player {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #3747C0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.player .eyes {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.player .eye_R {
  left: 7px;
  top: 10px;
}
.player .eye_L {
  left: 32px;
  top: 10px;
}
.player .mouth {
  height: 8.5px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: calc((50px - 32px)/2);
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-0 {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-1 {
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-2 {
  bottom: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-3 {
  bottom: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-4 {
  bottom: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-5 {
  bottom: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-6 {
  bottom: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-7 {
  bottom: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}

.ypos-8 {
  bottom: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.xpos-0 {
  left: 0px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-1 {
  left: 50px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-2 {
  left: 100px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-3 {
  left: 150px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-4 {
  left: 200px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-5 {
  left: 250px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-6 {
  left: 300px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-7 {
  left: 350px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-8 {
  left: 400px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-9 {
  left: 450px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-10 {
  left: 500px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-11 {
  left: 550px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-12 {
  left: 600px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-13 {
  left: 650px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-14 {
  left: 700px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-15 {
  left: 750px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-16 {
  left: 800px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-17 {
  left: 850px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.xpos-18 {
  left: 900px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "game">
 <div class = "player">
  <div class = "eyes eye_R"></div>
  <div class = "eyes eye_L"></div>
  <div class = "mouth"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `transition: 0.5s` to you `.player` class, this will smooth the movement. I'd also consider using css translate to move the object since changing top, left, right and bottom calls a redraw which will cause frame drops latter down the rode.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Here's a nice read on animation perfomance:
http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/

if you want to "fall" after jumping you'll also need to add code for that

```
if (event.which == 38) {
    if ($player.position().top > 0) {
        $player.css("top", "-=10");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $player.css("top", "+=10");
        }, 500); //500 since I suggested 0.5s in css transition
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: fixed spelling mistake in "transition", and added code for "falling"

Comment: try changing the transition to only affect "top" i.e. transition: top 0.5s and also experiment with changing the "jump" amount. You'll also want to add some code to prevent multiple jumps while it's still animating or modify the "falling" logic if you do. Here's a fork of your codepen + the jumping changes. http://codepen.io/nottu/pen/ENXxZo